# django use template tag in has_perm()

Tags: django, templatetags

I my project I have to use a model less permission. I wrote my own template tags in order to show or not an action button or content in a template. Here my template tags:

```
from django.template import Library
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

register = Library()


@register.filter(name='is_allowed_for')
def is_allowed_for(permission, user):
    if user.has_perm(permission.title()):
        return True

    return False


@register.filter(name='in_department')
def in_department(permission, department_name):
    if permission != '':
        new_permission = department_name.title() + '.' + permission.title()
    else:
        new_permission = department_name.title()
    return new_permission
```

In my template this works like expected: (department_name is passed from the view)

```
{% if 'Dashboard.View'|in_department:department_name|is_allowed_for:user %}
    has Department Dasboard view
{% else %}
    has not Department Dasboard view
{% endif %}
```

This does not work, I receive a TemplateSytaxError:

```
{% if user.has_perm('Dashboard.View'|in_department:department_name) %}
    has Department Dasboard view
{% else %}
    has not Department Dasboard view
{% endif %}
```

Isn't the tag applied before the has_perm method is called? Or what is wrong...? Thx for any help.

Comment: The problem isn't the tag, it's the parentheses.

Comment: Thx for the response. So, the second approach is not possible?

Comment: No. But why don't you write a filter that does all this, including calling has_perm?

Comment: in_department and is_allowed are filters or not ? Do you have a link with examples?